# What books do keyboard students use when learning figured bass?

Tags: harmony

What books do keyboard students use when learning figured bass?
Are there any standard books ttat is being used by students?

Comment: The best „books“ imho are the harpsichord accompaniments of the concerti by Handel and Bach. Some of them you‘ll find set in chords. Also the the basso continuo of Chorales, Cantatas and Passions can teach us everything - with a little help by wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

For the ABRSM Harpsichord syllabus, figured bass realisation is [a requirement](https://gb.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/other-instruments/harpsichord-exams/). [This forum](https://forums.abrsm.org/?showtopic=54456) has a few suggestions.

Chief of them are:

- [Figured Harmony at the Keyboard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Figured-Harmony-Keyboard-Part-Pt/dp/0193214717) by Morris, which comes in two parts;
- [Continuo Playing According to Handel: His Figured Bass Exercises](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Continuo-Playing-According-Handel-Exercises/dp/0193184338) by Ledbetter.
- [The Art of Accompaniment from a Thorough-Bass as Practiced in the XVIIth and XVIIIth Centuries](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Accompaniment-Thorough-Bass-Practiced-XVIIIth-Centuries/dp/0486431886), by FT Arnold, also in two volumes.

Then of course, you can always knock yourself out with an original-language [treatise](https://imslp.org/wiki/Der_General-Bass_in_der_Composition_(Heinichen%2C_Johann_David)) (hope you've learnt to play your keyboard in soprano clef).

A list of other sources can be found [here](http://www.charlston.co.uk/Thorough-Bass.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I had to play and harmonize the 150 figured basses by Pedron. I was asked to play them spontaneous without writing them down. This was absolutely horrible!

I’ve just found this link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partimento

It says different composers wrote exercises for studying figured bass.

*Partimento (from Italian: partimento, plural partimenti) is an instructive bass line with either figured or not configured bass.  Partiments were mainly used in the 18th and 19th centuries as educational aids for the teaching of harmony, counterpoint and improvisation.*

I think this table is useful:

http://robertkelleyphd.com/home/figured-bass/